# Возврат функции при соблюдения условия

Tags: php

Допустим есть функция, которая возвращает случайную цифру:

```
function getNumber()
{
    $Numbers = '1234567890';
    $NumbersSize = strlen($Numbers) - 1;
    $getNumber = $Numbers[rand(0, $NumbersSize)];
    return $getNumber;
}
```

Как заставить ее возвращать только нужную мне цифру, с помощью цикла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$getNumber = $Numbers[rand(0, $NumbersSize)];
while($getNumber != $nuzhnajaCifra)
  $getNumber = $Numbers[rand(0, $NumbersSize)];
return $getNumber;
```

Но не проще ли без цикла:

```
return $nuzhnajaCifra;
```